# New Post Notifications for Users - BUDDYPRESS

Tags: buddypress, notifications

I am using beneath code im buddypress to show notification of the latest posts posted by users.

https://gist.github.com/kishoresahoo/9209b9f6ac69ce21cd6962e7fe21e1b4/6b9d901383da4783f9108ffdc6aa2bb4e671cd44

The problem is that when a post is posted then only the person who posts the post receive the notification and the other users don't receive.

I want to fix this error.

Thanks and regards,
Ahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like JItendra Rana already mentioned, you just send a notification to the author. If all users should get a notification, you must loop through all your users and add a notification to everyone. You get the users with [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users). Here is the modified code to realize it:

```
function bp_post_published_notification( $post_id, $post ) {
    $author_id = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $users = get_users();

    /* Loop all users */
    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        if ( bp_is_active( 'notifications' ) ) {
            bp_notifications_add_notification( array(
                'user_id'           => $user->ID,
                'item_id'           => $post_id,
                'component_name'    => 'custom',
                'component_action'  => 'custom_action',
                'date_notified'     => bp_core_current_time(),
                'is_new'            => 1,
            ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'bp_post_published_notification', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: I would suggest using 'bp_core_get_users' where you can filter users based on buddypress function. Yours will work to. But using ' bp_core_get_users ' will give more flexibility

Comment: Sure. You're right.

Comment: Hi is it also possible to pull notifications upon [EventOn] (http://www.myeventon.com/) Plugin new event submission.

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but you have to search for the action which is triggered, when a new event is created and then hook the creation of a notification to this action.

According to [this](http://www.myeventon.com/documentation/getting-started-with-eventon-adding-events/) it seems, that the plugin uses the standard WordPress publishing, so you can use the action **publish_post** (like above) and check for the post type:
`if ( $post->post_type == 'xx')`

Answer (score 2):

If you check the function for 'publish_post' action.

```
function bp_post_published_notification( $post_id, $post ) {
    $author_id = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    if ( bp_is_active( 'notifications' ) ) {
        bp_notifications_add_notification( array(
            'user_id'           => $author_id,
            'item_id'           => $post_id,
            'component_name'    => 'custom',
            'component_action'  => 'custom_action',
            'date_notified'     => bp_core_current_time(),
            'is_new'            => 1,
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'bp_post_published_notification', 99, 2 );
```

Notice that you are sending Notification to Post Author only. 
You will need to change 'user_id' parameter in 'bp_notifications_add_notification' function to the user id you want.

Here is the [Codex Documentation](https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/function-examples/bp_notifications_add_notification/) for **bp_notifications_add_notification** Function.

---

**EDIT :**

Update the function as below :

```
function bp_post_published_notification( $post_id, $post ) {
    // $author_id = $post->post_author; 

    $active_users = bp_core_get_users( array("per_page"=>-1));

    foreach ( $active_users['users'] as $user ) {
        if ( bp_is_active( 'notifications' ) ) {
            bp_notifications_add_notification( array(
                'user_id'           => $user->ID,
                'item_id'           => $post_id,
                'component_name'    => 'custom',
                'component_action'  => 'custom_action',
                'date_notified'     => bp_core_current_time(),
                'is_new'            => 1,
            ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'bp_post_published_notification', 99, 2 );
```

[Click here](http://hookr.io/functions/bp_core_get_users/) for more details about **'bp_core_get_users'** function.

Comment: i want to send notification to all user id

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.